# Timer1_tick is not working until postback event

Tags: asp.net

As per topic in discussed. I've assigned one Timer1_Tick (AJAx Control) into my web form user control but it is not working right until i've perform "__doPostBack" in client side and it is not be able to perform automatically once the form is loaded.

```
Code in markup:
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="TimeSheetUpdate" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TimeSheetTimer"  EventName="Tick"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="TimeSheetTimer" Interval="1000" runat="server" OnTick="TimeSheetTimer_Tick" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

Code Behind:
protected void TimeSheetTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           File.WriteAllText(@"C:\checkTimesheetcontrol.txt", "");
           File.AppendAllText(@"C:\checkTimesheetcontrol.txt", "Check :" + DateTime.Now.Second);
           return;
       }
```

I need it to be perform ealier once the control in loaded in page.How Can I do for it?

Comment: why do you need `UpdatePanel` for `Timer`?

Comment: It works well for me. Is this your exact markup? Since `ChildrenAsTriggers` is `true` by default, you could remove the `Triggers` section. Also, setting `ClientIDMode` to `Static` does not mix well with UpdatePanel (usually), so you can also remove it.